# One dll or many?

Tags: architecture, .net

I currently have one "library" dll that has one module for each topic: Text, Reflection, Security, Math, FileSystem, FTP, Mail, Serialization, etc.

In each module are public helper methods that may call .Net framework methods or other helper methods.

In the past, I have had multiple dlls, each dedicated to a topic. This proved to be much harder to manage as there was some inter-dependency among the dlls (why not use library methods inside the library?), and they would get out of sync. Not to mention, circular dependencies are not allowed.

Here is my library, and you can see the circular dependency in one case
[image]

I'm having difficulty grasping this:

> "Uncle Bob" Martin of Clean Code:
>
> **The Release Reuse Equivalency Principle**: The granule of reuse is the granule of release.

What's the best architectural standard for organizing a library of modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ask yourself **whether it makes sense for a consumer of a library to use one part of it without using another one**.

Let's say you've developed a library which parses [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) files, processes LESS files into non-minified CSS files and minifies CSS files.

- Does it make sense to have a library which does just the parsing? For general use, not really. But it makes total sense for a person who wants to, say, create a linter for LESS files.
- Does it make sense to have a library which does just processing? Probably not. OK, it might be that somebody writes a parser which is faster and better than yours, but this person will probably also write his own processing engine as well. Therefore, a processor without a parser is not very useful.
- Does it make sense to have a library which minifies CSS and ignores everything related to LESS? Completely.

As a result, we have not one, but two libraries:

- LESS parser and processor, which depends on...
- ...CSS minifier.

Why two instead of three? Well, the general use, as previously explained, is to use the parser and the processor together. There is a rare case where the parser can be used independently, this doesn't justify the cost of making two libraries (although you or your team may decide that such case is still important and you should have two separate libraries).

In practice:

1. If you are **constantly seeing yourself including two libraries side by side** and there are practically no cases where you include one without another one (or the other way around in a case where there is a dependency), **merge** the libraries.
2. If you **constantly use only a part of the library** and this part looks like being logically distinct from other parts, **split** the library.

---

I also noticed a few points I want to highlight but which are unrelated to the question itself. Consider it a sort of comment:

- Have you looked at the organization of .NET Framework itself?
- The "public functions that wrap .NET Framework functions" sound scary. Why doing all this work? What's the point in calling your methods instead of .NET Framework ones?
- Functions and methods are not the same thing. I believe you're taking about methods here.
- If you end up getting circular dependencies, it might indicate that your architecture is deeply flawed.
- By new ship, do you mean a complete rewrite? If yes, you may be interested by [an article by Joel Spolsky](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000069.html).

Comment: 1. No, I have not, good idea. 2. helper functions, not helpful? 3. Loose terminology. Edited. Little bit of C terminology got in there, I guess. 4. Would you say that a library dll of modules containing helper routines that may call into each other or use other helper routines in other modules, is flawed? 5. Yes. I'll check it out. Thanks!

Comment: I'm assuming you realize this is not a class library and as a whole it has no single purpose, other than DRY. So nothing in it will never be the subject or object of composition.

Comment: @toddmo Function composition is still a kind of composition. MainMa is on the right track; things that are frequently used/needed together should come bundled together. Things which aren't, shouldn't. If I need to do some text processing, I don't want to drag in a bunch of windowing toolkit code or encryption functions. Where to draw the line is somewhat subjective, but it's not difficult to recognize when you're too close to the extremes (one function per `dll`, or a god `dll` that encompasses various libraries.)

Comment: @Doval, I looked it over and nothing depends on anything, except a few places use the `Text` module. I have 24 modules representing clearly separable Areas Of Responsibility. Should I break into 24 dlls? Or use artificial "categories" to group into a fewer number of dlls? What would you do?

Comment: @toddmo As long as you don't introduce any backwards-incompatible changes I don't see a problem with 24 `dll`s; you'll always be able to update any `dll` and have everything just work. The worst that can happen is that a newer version of a `dll` depends on a newer version of another `dll`, but again, updating won't break anything. If you do need to make a breaking change, make a new library so there's never any clashes (e.g. `foo.dll` -> `foo2.dll`, `namespace Foo` -> `namespace Foo2`, etc). That's pretty much how it works in Linux, where shared libraries are the norm.